# Как по клику onclick двигать элемент много раз ? у меня срабатывает только один раз

Tags: javascript

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
var width = box.offsetWidth;

document.querySelector('#prev').onclick = function() {
  box.style.left = width + 'px'
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Добавь кнопкам атрибут onclick И опиши в функциях эти document.style

Comment: <button id="prev" onclick="prev()">prev</button>; function prev(){
    box.style.left = width +'px'
};  Так же срабатывает один раз

Comment: я не могу понять логику, подскажите, почему срабатывает только один раз ? я примерно понимаю, что по заверению функции, она стирается, но как сделать чтобы она повторялась каждый раз снова и снова по клику. У меня небольшой опыт

Comment: потому что из разу в разу устанавливает одно и то же значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ты просто не то выбрал.

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.style.transform += 'translateX(1px)';

})


next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.style.transform += 'translateX(-1px)';

})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Еще второй вариант

```js
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0],
  prev = document.getElementById('prev'),
  next = document.getElementById('next');

function _count(direction) {
  let positionElemX = parseInt(getComputedStyle(box)["left"]);

  if (direction === '_next') {
    box.style.left = (positionElemX + 1) + 'px';
  } else if (direction === '_prev') {
    box.style.left = (positionElemX - 1) + 'px';
  }
}

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  _count('_prev')
})
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  _count('_next')
})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: как у тебя может двигаться элемент, если ты его не двигаешь, а просто задаешь позицию? подумай!!!

Comment: кажется я догнал)) спс

Comment: Ой.. Такая куча translate'ов навешивается...