# Добавление высоты к top через js

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь создать прокрутку блока при клике на кнопку. Идея такова:
При клике кнопки вниз добавлять к элементу изначально имеющему `top:0`, `10px`. И так до определенного предела, например `200px`, далее запретить добавление. Так же и вверх, когда доходит до нуля - запретить добавление. JQuery не вариант, нужен нативный JS.

Буду рад примерам.

Comment: Ответ нашел тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716659/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-onclick-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD

Однако и преложенный ответ так же работает. Но мне привычнее по примеру в ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом как-то так:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');

document.getElementById('bottom').onclick = function(e) {
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollTop > 190 ? 200 : div.scrollTop + 10;
}

document.getElementById('top').onclick = function(e) {
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollTop < 10 ? 0 : div.scrollTop - 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollDiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 100px;">
  Много строк <br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
  Много строк<br>
</div>

<a href="#" id="bottom">bottom</a>
<a href="#" id="top">top</a>
```